# Is there a way to ignore a query if it doesn't exist instead of getting an error?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the code below and am trying to use it to delete an item when a button is pressed. I used chain to set two queries and list the results. Now what I'm trying to do is allow the user to delete anything thats on the list with a button. When i test it however, I get an error that one of the 2 query sets dont exist. Is there a way to just force it to pass on to the next line of code if it doesn't exist vs giving me an error?

```
 Error:signedup matching query does not exist.


page = request.POST.get("page", False)

      if page == "delete":
         pk = request.POST.get("item")


         dancer = signedup.objects.get(pk=pk)
         team = team_signup.objects.get(pk=pk)
         if dancer == None:
           team.delete()
         elif team == None:
            dancer.delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put exception handling in:

```
try:
    dancer = signedup.objects.get(pk=pk)
except signedup.DoesNotExist:
    # handle error
```

My answer will fix the exceptions your getting, but it looks like you've got some other issues with your code:

- Why would your `team_signup` and `signedup` share a primary key?
- Why do you try to delete both types of things at once?

You probably should be passing a single primary key (for the object being deleted) and the type of the object so you know what to delete from where.

Comment: Team_signup and signedup are two different tables however I joined them with itertools chain so that I can list them in a cart and send to paypal. its not that they share a primary key, I'm just thinking if a team_signups instance was chosen to be deleted and had a primary key of 5, but there was also another object in signedup with a primary key of 5 , they would both be deleted because I'm calling on both tables individually with the same pk. get deleted

Comment: That's what I mean, you presumably don't want to delete both just because their primary keys *happen* to match up. In your POST, you want to add another field called type and then do: `if type == "team": team.delete() elif type == "dancer": dancer.delete()` or something along those lines.

Comment: yes that was going to be my next question but you answered it, thanks for your insight!!